# Is the ring of entire functions coherent?

Tags: commutative-algebra, several-complex-variables

Call a commutative ring $R$  *coherent* if for each $n\in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and each $n$-tuple $(r_1, \dots, r_n)$ in $R^n$, 
the kernel of the map 
$$R^n\owns (s_1, \dots, s_n) \mapsto r_1 s_1 +\cdots + r_n s_n\in R$$ 
is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

This notion of coherence is equivalent to other standard definitions, for example that every finitely generated ideal is finitely presented, or that the intersection of any two finitely generated ideals is finitely generated and every ring element  $a $ is such that  $\mathrm{Ann}(a)=0 $.

> Is the ring of entire functions in $d$ complex variables a coherent ring?

Comment: Do you happen to know offhand if the ring you're talking about is a Prufer domain? Or a Bezout domain?

Comment: Dear @rschwieb: why not  ask these questions on a separate thread, for clarity's sake?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Because an affirmative answer gives a simple solution to the problem at hand. I don't think it's worth starting a whole new question for something I am not really interested in and then coming back here and pointing to the answer.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb: ok, here are the answers.  The ring $R=\mathcal O(\mathbb C^n)$ is not Prüfer for $n\geq2$ because the ideal $I=(z_1,...,z_n)$ is not invertible, since $I^{-1}=R$ and thus $I\cdot I^{-1}=I\neq R$ . Since Bézout implies Prüfer, that  ring is not Bézout either. For $n=1$ the ring $\mathcal O(\mathbb C)$ is well known (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout_domain#Examples) to be Bézout and is thus Prüfer too.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : I knew the single variable case was Prufer, but I don't know anything about the multivariable case. Alas since it's not the case we can't use the semihereditary $\implies$ coherent implication...

Comment: Dear @rschwieb, allow me to  disagree with your "Alas": I would be very happy if there were no elementary proof of coherence! This would show Martin Brandenburg and people of similar disposition that techniques of complex analytic geometry involving coherent sheaves and the like (which were my first love in mathematics) are really necessary, even for **apparently** elementary problems on  holomorphic functions :-)

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg : hah! This association of my comment with your exchange with Martin is a little disturbing but mostly amusing :) Please don't think so much of it. Don't you think it is fairly natural to wonder if two properties that hold in the single variable case might hold off the multivariable case? And even if it's ruled out, as it was here, it lends more strength to your case that there may not be a simplistic approach. And we get a good example of a coherent but not semihereditary ring to boot. I don't think there is anything here to be disagreeable about :)

Comment: Dear @rschwieb,  be assured that I meant nothing disturbing in my comment (but I'm happy to hear that it mostly amused you!). I understand and even sympathize with the wish to have a completely elementary solution  but  since nobody (yet?) has given  such a solution  I am happy to have an opportunity to advertize the power  of sheaves , which I consider  a beautiful and natural tool in the context of this question. And you are quite right that one can disagree  without being disagreeable :)